# Connect to undetected-chromedriver docker image

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, selenium, undetected-chromedriver

I have been using https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome on my Synology NAS to use Selenium Webdriver to perform automated requests.

I don't remember the command I ran but I started the container and run `driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub")` in Python to connect to the selenium chrome image.

However I have a use case that requires me to use [undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver). How do I install something like https://hub.docker.com/r/bruvv/undetected_chromedriver and connect to it from my NAS' python terminal?

Comment: So what you are saying is you need to containerize the undetected-chromedriver?

Comment: @jabbson yes that is correct

Comment: Do you know how would you use non-dockerized undetected-chromedriver for the same task, what steps would you take, given you weren't doing it in docker environment?

Comment: I would just follow [this code](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver#the-version-2-way)

Comment: but it isn't quite the same now, is it. In the first case, you are using the selenium, which loads the standalone chromedriver, starts the remote server and exposes a port to connect to, with undetected-chromedriver, it is just the driver. Do you know how to interconnect selenium with this undetected-chromedriver? Unless I terribly misunderstand the concept, of course :)

Comment: @Bijan Hey ! How did you end up connecting the remote webdriver to the undetected-webdriver? Did you simply substitute the `standalone-chrome` image in your docker-compose & it worked ? Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beware, everyone can publish on docker hub and so there are numerous undetected-chromedriver's. So what you are trying to install is someone else's (failed) attempt.

official: https://hub.docker.com/r/ultrafunk/undetected-chromedriver

as per @nnhthuan 's comment, some more detail.

undetected-chromedriver will start the Chrome binary, but will do it from python instead of letting the chromedriver binary run Chrome. As undetected-chromedriver does not officially support headless mode, you'll need a way to run "windowed" chrome on docker. To make this happen, you could use Xvfb to emulate a X-server desktop. If you forget this step, you won't be able to connect to chrome as chrome closes itself down (no screens found) even before undetected-chromedriver is able to connect, and so it crashes.

To ensure xvfb keeps running, you could use for example something like this in your entrypoint:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:1
function keepUpScreen() {
  echo "running keepUpScreen()"
  while true; do
        sleep .25
        if [ -z $(pidof Xvfb) ]; then
                Xvfb $DISPLAY -screen $DISPLAY 1280x1024x16 &
        fi;
  done;
}


keepUpScreen &
echo "running: ${@}"
exec "$@"
```

once your image is running stable, you could set your chromedriver debug_host to your internal ip address instead of 127.0.0.1, and debug_port to a static value. This would enable connections from remote hosts.
Don't forget to forward them in docker.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32010639)